# Run time error '3706': Provider cannot be found -Visual Basic

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to connect Visual Basic to MS Access using ADODB. But as I execute my code, it prompts: "Provider cannot be found.It may not be installed properly." But when I check on my directory I've got my "msjetoledb40.dll" installed.

Here is my code:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rec As ADODB.Recordset

    Sub sample()

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    conn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB 4.0;Data Source=C:\sample.mdb;Persist Security Info=false;")
End Sub
```

Comment: I have same Error! In my case I am trying to connect to Sql Database with Oracle 11g Installed with Office 365 Excel VB Script. I have installed MDAC Driver, Still issue is unresolved.

Answer (score 3):

This would be better:

```
Sub sample()

  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rec As ADODB.Recordset
  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
  conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\sample.mdb;"
  conn.Open
End Sub
```

You missed a point.

Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB 4.0 => Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Ref: http://www.connectionstrings.com/.

Comment: Oh! How a single '.' could ruin your code. Thank you, this is another lesson to me.

Answer (score 3):

Confirming the version of your MS Office on which the script is running. If you have installed MS Office 2013 or later, you should revise the connection string from:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB 4.0;Data Source=C:\sample.mdb;Persist Security Info=false;
```

to:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\sample.mdb;Persist Security Info=false;
```

At least, this sovled my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Error 3706

```
cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Just Change 12.0  for 15.0

```
cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=" & sPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
```

and works, always you must to try change the version of the controller!.